Is it possible to own the zero-address and the dEaD one?
What do you think it would mean if the same person is the owner of the Genesis wallet address(0) as well as the Dead wallet 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dEaD?
What do you think would be the equivalent value

Owning an address means knowing the private key for which if you hashed the public key and took the last 20 bytes, you would obtain that address. A private key is any 256-bit number (except 0), meaning there are
115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639934
possibilities.
If you take all the bitcoin miners in the world (currently totaling 600 Exahash/second) and ask them to stop mining and instead, try to to find the private key of all the address, it would take them
6119571771801337911359028042485197227151508575682
years to compute all possible addresses.
At the same time, there's a non zero chance that you just type a random number from the top of your head and find that it's the private key for Vitalik Buterin's wallet.
In general, you can type any sequence of 40 hex characters that you didn't obtain by taking the last 20 bytes of the hash of a public key, and be fairly certain that no one owns it.
The address zero has a special meaning for smart contracts because it's the value that any address variable will have if it has never been set to anything else. The address 0x000..000dead is an arbitrary address that has a special meaning to humans because it contains the word "dead". But you can pick any address you want and say "this is a dead address". However if you want people to believe you that it's actually not a wallet that you secretly hold the private key for somewhere hidden, it has to be obviously special to the human eye. Something like
0xfafafafafafafafafafafafafafafafafafafafa
